# Does a non pipelined processor run a whole instruction in one cycle, or one cycle for each stage?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Every body knows that an instruction to be executed must be divided in a number of stages like instruction fetch , instruction decode and so on .......

In a pipelined CPU, every stage is done in one cycle and maybe  different stages for different instructions done in one cycle (instructions overlap in different stages)

In a non pipelined processor instructions are done Sequentially (there is no overlap).  In such a processor, are instructions done completely (all stages) in one cycle or each stage of it done in one cycle?

Comment: multi-cycle or single-cycle non-pipelined implementations are possible.  Multi-cycle is common for old microcoded CPUs like 8086 and 6502.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to implement a non-pipelined CPU which evaluates each instruction in one cycle. See [J1 core](http://www.excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html) for example: data is fetched from the block RAMs on a rising edge of the clock and writeback is done on a falling edge.

Instructions can be simple enough to have the critical path short (and clock rate reasonably high).

Although, most of the historical pre-RISC cores used to be multi-cycle. A typical design of such a CPU is explained [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~jchargo/portfolio/MulticycleProcessor.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Every instruction has at least to be fetched from cache (1 cycle) and to be decoded (1 cycle). Only then can it be executed (nr of cycles depends on the instruction). It is thus impossible to execute any instruction (including its fetch and decode) in 1 cycle.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to fetch, decode, execute and write back in a single cycle (of course, if your memory allows it). It will only make your critical path longer (and clock rate lower).

Comment: You are in principle right, but it would also in principle be right to say you can execute a whole program in a single cycle...

Comment: No, you cannot execute a whole program in a single cycle. But you can have one read and one write per port per block RAM in a single cycle. See the J1 core I've mentioned in my answer for example.

Comment: Yes, you can, in principle. If you have a VERY long word processor that can read the whole program in one cycle, and a parallel memory that can do multiple write in one cycle.

Comment: Only if your program is linear, with no branching at all.